# jquery tools error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=/]

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I just loaded jQuery Tools onto my site. But the Google Chrome console shows an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=/] (http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js)
```

The jQuery version I am using is 1.7.1

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Post the part of your HTML code where you load jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a selector that is meant to match elements with an `href` attribute value of `/`. You will need to put the `/` character in quotes:

```
var elems = $("[href='/']");
```

Alternatively, you can escape the character:

```
var elems = $("[href=\\/]");
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ5JS/). Remove the quotes to generate the same error you mention in your question.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at it. But it's strange because I have plenty of other scripts on this site and never had this error. And it appeared just after adding JQuery Tools. I don't even use it, just loaded.

Comment: My comment above  is wrong. After deleting JQuery Tools, the error now occurrs in JQuery itself. So I just didn't notice it before.

Comment: All is clear. It was actually an error in one of the other scripts that I am using on this site, and it's exactly using href=/ without quotes. Thanks for the tip. (My fault I didn't look at the call stack for this error in Chrome, it would be quicker to find)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you changed the order of the libraries. If you want to use JQuery, its lib has to be loaded first to use an additional JQuery-Expansion-Lib. You should change the order in the `<head>` like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formate.css"> //CSS always first
  <script src="URL_TO_JQUERY" type="text/javascript"></script> //JQuery first
  <script src="URL_TO_ADDITIONAL_LIB_1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="URL_TO_ADDITIONAL_LIB_..." type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="URL_TO_ADDITIONAL_LIB_n" type="text/javascript"></script>   
 </head>
</html>
```